# Google Apps Script For Loop To Grab Cell Values and Insert into Formula

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script

I have 5 possible locations where a user can enter either: "Yes, No, or any URL". If a URL is entered, I need the value of that cell (the URL) to be entered into an equation on a corresponding cell in a separate sheet. Here is what I have:

```
  //Locations of the cells where the user can enter the URL.
  var graphic1_loc = 'A62';
  var graphic2_loc = 'A63';
  var graphic3_loc = 'A64';
  var graphic4_loc = 'A65';
  var graphic5_loc = 'A66';

  //The corresponding locations on the "Briefing" sheet where the images would get inserted.
  var graphic1_placement = 'B45';
  var graphic2_placement = 'B46';
  var graphic3_placement = 'B47';
  var graphic4_placement = 'B48';
  var graphic5_placement = 'B49';

  //main_gen is the name of the sheet where the user enters the data. This just grabs the value
  //the user entered and stores it in the corresponding variable.

  var graphic1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('main_gen!'+graphic1_loc).getValue();
  var graphic2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('main_gen!'+graphic2_loc).getValue();
  var graphic3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('main_gen!'+graphic3_loc).getValue();
  var graphic4 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('main_gen!'+graphic4_loc).getValue();
  var graphic5 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('main_gen!'+graphic5_loc).getValue();
  var graphics_placements = ["B45", "B46", "B47", "B48", "B49"]; //These are the corresponding cells where the image would be placed on a separate sheet.

//If any graphic is a URL, insert that image into it's corresponding cell in the Briefing tab.
  for (var num = 0; num < 5; num ++) {
    var graphicformula = '=IMAGE("' + graphic[num] + '",1)';
    if (graphic[num].length > 5) {
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('Briefing!'+graphic[num]_placement).setFormula(graphicformula);
    }
  }
```

What I am trying to get the If statement within the For Loop to say is...If the length of the value of graphic1 is > 5 (if it isn't yes (3) or no (2) then it is assumed it is a URL) then find the corresponding cell on the "Briefing" sheet to insert the formula. The current way I have it written is not correct, but I wanted to attempt to write something to give you an idea of what I am after. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to run `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('Briefing!'+graphic[num]_placement).setFormula(graphicformula);` when the value of `graphic#` is URL.
- For example, when the URL is in the cell `A63` in the sheet `main_gen`, you want to put the formula of `=IMAGE(URL,1)` to the cell `B46` in the sheet `Briefing`

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, you are trying to use `graphic[num]` as a variable of `graphic1, graphic2,,,`. In this case, this cannot be used as the variable.
- In your situation, the cells `A62:A66` in the sheet `main_gen` are correspoinding to the cells `B45:B49` in the sheet `Briefing`. I think that this can be used for modifying your script.

  - The values of the cells `A62:A66` in the sheet `main_gen` can be retrieved by `ss.getSheetByName("main_gen").getRange("A62:A66").getValues()`.
- In order to confirm whether the value of cell is the URL, in this modification, I used `test()`.
- I think that when the destination sheet is declared out of the for loop, the process cost can be reduced.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var source = ss.getSheetByName("main_gen").getRange("A62:A66").getValues();
var dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Briefing");
var graphics_placements = ["B45", "B46", "B47", "B48", "B49"];
for (var num = 0; num < source.length; num ++) {
  if (/https?:\/\//.test(source[num][0])) {
    var graphicformula = '=IMAGE("' + source[num][0] + '",1)';
    dstSheet.getRange(graphics_placements[num]).setFormula(graphicformula);
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: @hunter21188 Thank you for replying. In your situation, the 3 patterns of "yes", "no" and URL are used. So I proposed to use `test()`. For example, I think that `if (source[num][0].toUpperCase() != "YES" && source[num][0].toUpperCase() != "NO" ) {}` can be also used instead of `test()`. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.